# Drawing video on HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas, html5-video, getusermedia

Is it possible to get the live video feed from webcam into an HTML5 canvas element directly ? Right now I use an HTML5 video tag to get User Media and then paint each frame of video element to a canvas element.

Is it possible to get user media directly painted on canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick googling around and it seems like no :(,

There is a lot of answers which follow your solution by capturing the webcam, converting that data and then drawing inside of the canvas like so : http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2013/08/webcam-to-canvas-or-data-uri-with-html5-and-javascript/